# Text truncated in Azure Monitor Workbook Table Columns

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

Im trying to write queries on Azure Workbook so that I can run queries on our logs, which would allow me to drill down and view exactly what the exception message is. While doing so, when I execute a KQL query, on the workbooks, the column values are truncated as shown in picture. I want to be able to see the full error stack in order to troubleshoot the issue. Now I can get the operation_Id from here and then run it in Log Analytics to view full details, but I would like to view everything I need on this single page within Azure WorkBook. Clicking on the column doesn't expand it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expand a particular column when you execute a kql query on the workbooks.

If you change the visualization to `Text`  you will be able to see the complete stack error message as show in the below image

[image]

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to:
1. Display the text in json format
2. Display multiple columns without having to concatenate into single column

Comment: Below statements are based on our analysis,
 1. Display the text in json format 
 Ans: As shown in above screenshot the projected output is already in JSON format. 
2. Display multiple columns without having to concatenate into single column
 Ans: Using Text visualization you cannot display the output in multiple columns

Comment: or in the grid settings you can set the column renderer to be a link, and have that link open "cell details" .  that will open up a side pane that shows all the content of the cell in a popup view

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do something like this in workbooks, but the grid we use doesn't have the ability to expand a single cell like the logs view does.

- As another answer states, you could use the "text" visualization to visualize just one cell (0,0) as a text block, but that only works for once cell queries.
- or, in the grid settings you can set the column renderer to be a link for those columns, and have that link open the "cell details" view. that will open up a side pane that shows all the content of the cell in a popup view

  - or you could pick the "generic details" option which will open a side popup showing the values of all the columns in that row)
- or, you can go into advanced settings, and enable the option to export parameters when a row is selected.  you can then set it to export specific columns as specific named parameters, and use those parameters downstream to see values in something like a markdown text item in the workbook, or in a subsequent query.

there are examples of things like that documented here: https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/Interactivity.md